# How to resolve object' does not contain such a member Angular 7 and VS Code error

Tags: angular, angular-validation

In my Angular app, I am trying to display an error message if the email input field is invalid.

Here is what I currently have:

HTML:

```
<input [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': formErrors.email}" formControlName="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" (blur)="logValidationErrors()">
<div class="invalid-feedback">
    {{formErrors.email}}
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
validationMessages = {
    'email': {
        'required': 'Please provide your Email.',
        'emailDomain': 'Email domain should be gmail.com'
    }
};

formErrors = {};

logValidationErrors(group: FormGroup = this.signUpForm): void {
    Object.keys(group.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
    const abstractControl = group.get(key);

    this.formErrors[key] = '';
    if (abstractControl && abstractControl.invalid && (abstractControl.touched || abstractControl.dirty)) {
        const messages = this.validationMessages[key];

        for (const errorKey in abstractControl.errors) {
            if (errorKey) {
                this.formErrors[key] += messages[errorKey] + ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    if (abstractControl instanceof FormGroup) {
        this.logValidationErrors(abstractControl);
    }
    });
}
```

When I run this code with `ng serve`, the email field validation message is being displayed as soon as I type a single character into the input field.

However, when I look at my Typescript code in VS.code, I get the following error:

> Identifier 'email' is not defined. '__object' does not contain such a memberAngular

I've tried to resolve this error by making this change:

```
{{formErrors['email']}}
```

- Now, the VS Code error now goes away
- But the validation message is not displayed when I enter a single character.
- Instead, the validation message is only displayed once I leave the field.

Can someone please tell me why this is occurring & how I can resolve it?
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You seem to be using `FormGroup` why are you calling a custom function on `blur` instead of [angular formGroup validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#constructor()) ?

Answer (score 1):

You're overthinking it way too much.

When creating your control :

```
this.form = builder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.email]]
});
```

Also,

```
<input formControlName="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" (blur)="logValidationErrors()">
<div class="invalid-feedback" *ngIf="form.get('email').hasError('email')">
    {{validationMessages.email.emailDomain}}
</div>
```

*You don't need to add custom errors, since Angular adds `ng-invalid` when the control has an error*